# Laravel 5.7 artisan migrate

Tags: laravel-5.7

I installed recently laravel 5.7. How to fix error "php artisan migrate"?

```
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

  at C:\laravel\blg2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")      C:\laravel\blg2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\laravel\blg2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> Laravel uses the utf8mb4 character set by default, which includes support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them.

Inside your **AppServiceProvider**:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

...

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

> Alternatively, you may enable the innodb_large_prefix option for your database. Refer to your database's documentation for instructions on how to properly enable this option.

For more information about indexes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#indexes

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem @user2301515 :)

Answer (score 1):

> If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them.

You can have it fixed as Chin Leung said.

Or adding the length of the record directly in the migration.

$table->string('email', 100);   VARCHAR equivalent column with a optional length.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('email', 90)->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On **xampp php 7.3.2**, **laravel 5.7** & also in **laravel 5.8.3** it happened to me. Only changed the config/database.php file.

```
config/database.php
```

Changed charset & collation on mysql & it worked fine. Change this part

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

as

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Now it will accept the long keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to
 `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

Now Add the following code and then save and run php artisan serve

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

...

public function boot()
{
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

I use Laravel 5.7 but this error always comes up. ADD this code in every project. Also try to use Laravel with php7+ so that it doesnot show you `PDO::Exception Error...`

Answer (score 0):

Open your AppServiceProvider.php, Path >> App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
    namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
**use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;**

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        **Schema::defaultStringLength(191);**
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the string length as well to solve this kind of error

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name',20);
            $table->string('email',80)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password',8);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```